# Optmize detach model with a event listener

Tags: php, laravel

I have a destroy function which allows me to detach models (polymorphic relationship).

```
public function destroy {
  $vaccine = HealthItem::findOrFail($vaccine_id);

  $vaccine->detachCategories();

  $events = $vaccine->events()->get();

  foreach ($events as $event) {
    $event->detachCategories();
  };

  $vaccine->events()->delete();
  $vaccine->delete();
}
```

Here, I detach an "event" model with "detachCategories" (a helper to help me detach my categories)

I collect them and I do a foreach. It works, it is well detached from my table `categorizable`.

BUT I don't think it's great, right?

I'm going to have to do it for all of my `events`, every time a model is linked to it and it'll do a lot. So, I tried to make it an event but without success.

My Event Model :

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function ($event) {
        $event->categories()->detach();
    });
}
```

I delete the `event` with the following line `$vaccine->events()->delete();`

How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel Events](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/events) should get you there, and if its a big job and you have setup queue workers on your server, you should make sure the event listeners are queued.

The following solution should work:

You likely want to make a contract and a trait for this polymorphic relationship so that you can do better type hinting, and DRY up your code. You can put these in whatever folders make most sense for your project. Say:

```
interface CategorizableContract
{
   // Relationship to access the models categories
}

trait HasCategories
{
    // Implement methods above
  
    /**
     * Initialize the trait
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function bootHasCategories()
    {
        static::deleting(function($categorizable) {
            event(new DestroyCategorizable($categorizable));
        });
    }
}
```

Then in your models that have categories:

```
class Vaccine extends Model implements CategorizableContract
{
   use HasCategories;
   ...
}
```

Now we can make an event in App\Events:

```
class DestroyCategorizable
{
    use SerializesModels;
    
    /** @var CategorizableContract */
    public $categorizable;

    /**
     * Create an event for deleting categorizable models
     * 
     * @param CategorizableContract $categorizable
     *
     * @return void 
     */
    public function __construct(CategorizableContract $categorizable)
    {
        $this->categorizable = $categorizable;
    }
}
```

Now you can make an event listener, in App\Listeners, like so:

```
class DetachCategories implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function handle(DestroyCategorizable $event)
    {
         $categorizable = $event->categorizable;
         $class = new ReflectionClass($categorizable)

         // Detach the categories
         DB::table('categorizable')
             ->where('categorizable_type', $class->getName())
             ->where('categorizable_id', $categorizable->id)
             ->delete();
    }
}
```

Now just register your listener in your EventServiceProvider, and away you go!

```
    protected $listen = [
        DestroyCategorizable::class => [
            DetachCategories::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Now when you call delete on a model with categories, it will automatically detach them for you.

```
    $vaccine->delete();
```

Even though the model is deleted, it was serialized in the event, so its id and class type will be available to detach the categories in the listener. Hope that helps :)